# Why cost of Bitmap Heap Scan is not linear to number of rows

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

I have two parts of two analyze-explain outputs in postgres:

```
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on changegroup cg  (cost=332.95..23432.90 rows=17616 width=16) (actual time=1.728..68.845 rows=18091 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (issueid = 371928)
         Heap Blocks: exact=1606
```

and

```
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on changeitem ci  (cost=4439.94..87423.34 rows=205872 width=17) (actual time=65.291..4281.683 rows=208856 loops=1)
     Recheck Cond: ((field)::text = 'Flaky Count'::text)
     Heap Blocks: exact=25026
```

Postgres predicts that second query will have 4x bigger cost than first query despite number of rows predicted over 10x more.

What another strange thing is the real time of query for second one is not only 10x longer but even around 80x.

Why cost is even not linear to number of rows
   and 
why time is above linear to number of rows?

Comment: The number of table blocks visited is an important factor, and also if they were all in shared buffers.

Comment: What is the number of rows in each table (as opposed to the number of rows returned)? When was the last time each table was `VACUUM`ed?

Comment: Table was vacuumed last hour.
changeitem is 4 million.
changegroup is 3 million.
work_mem is 96mb.
shared_buffers 128mb.